# FLUTTER: Responsive Widgets with Zoom

Tags: android, flutter, dart, responsive-design, responsive

FLUTTER: How do I make my widgets (which use fontSize, height and width) responsive to device zoom? I always use MediaQuery.of(context).size for different phones resolutions, but what about when the problem is zooming?

**Picture without Zoom**

[image: Without Zoom]

**Picture with Zoom**

[image: With Zoom]

Answer (score 1):

Aside from MediaQuery, you can use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to check the parent widget's dimension and be able to adjust the child widget's dimension as needed.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  debugPrint('Max height: ${constraints.maxHeight}, max width: ${constraints.maxWidth}');
  return Container(); // create function here to adapt to the parent widget's constraints
}),
```

Overflow errors happen when the Widget displayed on screen exceeds its parent widget's dimension. What you can do here for the child widgets to adapt with the change in dimension is by setting Constraints - this helps set a minimum and max dimensions for the widget. You can check this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints) for more details.

```dart
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(
    minWidth: 70,
    minHeight: 70,
    maxWidth: 150,
    maxHeight: 150,
  ),
  child: YourButton(),
),
```